# How to inherit from ObservableValue?

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I have a class that contains a variety of properties:

```
public class Foo extends ??? {
    public SimpleBooleanProperty prop1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty prop2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    // ** more properties ** //
}
```

In most cases all the properties change and for some listeners it would be much easier to get only one callback called when any property changed and then get the values of all the properties (even if not all of them changed). What class should I build upon?

I would like to register a listener with something along the line of

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.addListener( new ChangeListener< >() {
      void onChange(Foo newValue,Foo oldValue) {
           System.out.println(String.valueOf(newValue.prop1.get());
           System.out.println(String.valueOf(newValue.prop2.get());
      });
```

Prinint to the console is just an example, the point is that a listener only needs to know that something changed, and its fine to call the getters. I am a bit lost where to start. There is the `Observable` interface, and a huge number of different base classes (eg `ObservableValueBase<T>` or `SimpleObjectProperty<T>`). Which one should I inherit from / extend?

Comment: you do not have to inherit anything. you must implement a method (addListener) that accepts EventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `ObservableValue<Foo>` as your listener suggests would mean your object is wrapping a `Foo` object which is clearly not the case.

For `ObservableValue` there would be classes to extend. For `Observable` no such class exists and you should implement the interface on your own. This could be done by adding/removing the listeners to/from all `Observable` properties, but for efficiency I recommend implementing this with a single listener per property:

```
public abstract class ObservableBase implements Observable {

    private final List<InvalidationListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    protected ObservableBase(Observable... dependencies) {
        InvalidationListener listener = o -> {
            for (InvalidationListener l : listeners) {
                try {
                    l.invalidated(o);
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        for (Observable o : dependencies) {
            o.addListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final void addListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
         Objects.requireNonNull(listener);
         listeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public final void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener) {
         listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

```
public class Foo extends ObservableBase {
    public final BooleanProperty prop1;
    public final StringProperty prop2;

    // ** more properties ** //

    private Foo(BooleanProperty prop1, StringProperty prop2) {
        super(prop1, prop2);
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    public Foo() {
        this(new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "prop1"), new SimpleStringProperty(this, "prop2"));
    }
}
```

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
InvalidationListener l = o -> {
    ReadOnlyProperty p = (ReadOnlyProperty) o;
    System.out.println("changed property: " + p.getName());

    Foo bean = (Foo) p.getBean();

    System.out.println(bean.prop1.get());
    System.out.println(bean.prop2.get());
};
foo.addListener(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I interpreted correctly what you need. This is probably what you need:

```
public class Foo extends ??? {
    public SimpleBooleanProperty prop1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty prop2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    // ** more properties ** //

    private final ObjectBinding<Void> binding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(this::bar, prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4);

    private final Void bar() {
        Optional.of(newValue.prop1.get()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
        Optional.of(newValue.prop2.get()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
        Optional.of(newValue.prop3.get()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
        Optional.of(newValue.prop4.get()).ifPresent(System.out::println);

        return null;
    }
}
```

The binding itself will do the listening for you, but you must keep a strong reference of the binding, or else it would be garbage collected.